# Http can only get httpbin.org

Tags: http, task, elm

When running the following program in `elm-reactor` (or using `elm-make` for that matter), the *only* webpage I have found that it actually `GET`s is [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/get). Otherwise, I see a Http.NetworkError, even on reliable sites such as "http://google.com" or "http://stackoverflow.com". I am utterly befuddled as to why this might be, can anyone point out my error?

```
module Main (..) where

import Http
import Html exposing (..)
import Effects
import Html.Events as Events
import StartApp
import Task


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
  { output : String }


type Action
  = Response String
  | Request String
  | HTTPError Http.Error



-- UPDATE


update : Action -> Model -> ( Model, Effects.Effects Action )
update act mod =
  case act of
    Response str ->
      ( { mod | output = str }, Effects.none )

    Request srv ->
      let
        effects =
          srv
            |> Http.getString
            |> Task.map Response
            |> flip Task.onError (Task.succeed << HTTPError)
            |> Effects.task
      in
        ( { mod | output = "GET: " ++ srv }, effects )

    HTTPError err ->
      ( { mod
          | output =
              "Error: "
                ++ case err of
                    Http.Timeout ->
                      "Timeout"

                    Http.UnexpectedPayload str ->
                      "Unexpected payload: " ++ str

                    Http.BadResponse code str ->
                      "Bad response: " ++ toString code ++ ": " ++ str

                    Http.NetworkError ->
                      "Network error"
        }
      , Effects.none
      )



-- VIEW


view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html.Html
view address mod =
  div
    []
    [ div
        []
        [ input
            [ Events.on "input" Events.targetValue (Request >> Signal.message address) ]
            []
        ]
    , div [] [ text mod.output ]
    ]



-- MAIN


app : StartApp.App Model
app =
  StartApp.start
    { init = ( { output = "No requests made" }, Effects.none )
    , update = update
    , view = view
    , inputs = []
    }


main =
  app.html


port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Effects.Never ())
port tasks =
  app.tasks
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely running into cross-origin browser restrictions. Take a look at your browser javascript console as you make requests that fail. Chrome logs an error like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.stackoverflow.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://elm-lang.org' is therefore not allowed access.

Your working httpbin example link includes the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which is the least restrictive setting.

You can read up more on these types of issues, and the way to get around them, by looking up information on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (which stands for Cross Origin Http Request).